# The alternating zeta function and functional equation

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

The Dirichlet eta function (the alternating zeta function) is given by

$$η(s)=∑_{n=1}^{∞}(-1)ⁿ⁻¹/n^{s}$$

The functional equation for $η(s)$ is given by

$$η(s)=ϕ(s)η(1-s)$$

where 
$$ϕ(s)=2(((1-2^{-1+s}))/(1-2^{s}))π^{s-1}sin(((πs)/2))Γ(1-s)$$

Apply it twice we get

$$(1-ϕ(1-s)ϕ(s))η(1-s)=0$$

Assume that $η(s)≠0$, then my **question** is: Can we deduce that $$1-ϕ(1-s)ϕ(s)=0$$ since $η(1-s)≠0$ or we get $$1-ϕ(1-s)ϕ(s)=0$$ for all $s∈ℂ$. Maybe I missing some thing!

Comment: Using trig and gamma information, try to prove that equation.

Comment: But yes, you can _deduce_ it from the functional equation and the fact that $\eta \not\equiv 0$.

Comment: @GEdgar: Yes, I do that, but nothing is clear.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I am afred that $1−ϕ(1−s)ϕ(s)=0$ for all $s∈C$.

Comment: You need: $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s) = \pi/\sin(\pi s)$.

Comment: You get $$1 - \phi(s)\phi(1-s) = 0$$ for all $s\in\mathbb{C}$ by the identity theorem. Since $\phi(s)\phi(1-s)$ is analytic, and the identity holds on a nonempty open set, it holds everywhere (maybe one needs to remove removable singularities of $\phi(s)\phi(1-s)$)

Comment: So ... $1-\phi(1-s)\phi(s)=0$ can be proved directly, without mention of the function $\eta$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: by *the identity holds on a nonempty open set* you mean the set where $η(s)≠0$.

Comment: Yes, although we need only a tiny subset of that to reach the conclusion.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thus, $1−ϕ(1−s)ϕ(s)=0$ except at the points where $ϕ(s)=0$, i.e., $s∈({1+i((2πm)/(ln2)),2l,0+i((2πk)/(ln2)),m,l,k∈ℤ})$

Comment: By the identity theorem, $\phi(1-s)\phi(s)$ has only removable singularities, so removing these, it even holds in zeros of $\phi$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ok and thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$ϕ(s)=2(((1-2^{-1+s}))/(1-2^{s}))π^{s-1}sin(((πs)/2))Γ(1-s)$$

$$ϕ(1-s)=2(((1-2^{-1+(1-s)}))/(1-2^{(1-s)}))π^{(1-s)-1}sin(((π(1-s))/2))Γ(s)$$

Let $s=α+iβ$ such that $ϕ(s)≠0$ and $ϕ(1-s)≠0$

then the equation

$$1-ϕ(1-s)ϕ(s)=0$$ imply

$$sin(πα)cosh(πβ)-2cos((1/2)πα)sin((1/2)πα)cosh²((1/2)πβ)-2cos((1/2)πα)sin((1/2)πα)sinh²((1/2)πβ)=0$$
and
$$cos(πα)sinh(πβ)-2cos²((1/2)πα)cosh((1/2)πβ)sinh((1/2)πβ)+2sin²((1/2)πα)cosh((1/2)πβ)sinh((1/2)πβ)=0$$
since the partial derivatives are all zero with respect to $α$ and $β$.